# How can I receive the "scroll box" type scroll events from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, scroll

I have a DataGridView, and I'm listening to its Scroll event.  This gives me a ScrollEventArgs object whose Type member is supposed to tell me the type of scroll event that has occurred.  On [the MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventtype.aspx) it says I should be able to detect movement of the scroll box by listening for events with types ThumbPosition, ThumbTrack, First, Last and EndScroll.

However, when I drag the scroll box, I only get events of type LargeDecrement and LargeIncrement.

How do I get access to the ThumbPosition, ThumbTrack, First, Last and EndScroll events?

Comment: You don't say what version of .NET you're using. And is it WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

bool addScrollListener(DataGridView dgv)
{
    bool ret = false;

    Type t = dgv.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("VerticalScrollBar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    ScrollBar s = null;

    if (pi != null)
        s = pi.GetValue(dgv, null) as ScrollBar;

    if (s != null)
    {
        s.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(s_Scroll);
        ret = true;
    }

    return ret;
}

void s_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    // Hander goes here..
}
```

As you'd expect, if you want to listen to horizontal scroll events, you change "VerticalScrollBar" to "HorizontalScrollBar"

Comment: Thanks for that - works great. pi.GetValue(o, null) should be pi.GetValue(dgv, null) if anyone wonders.

Comment: Don't forget to add addScrollListener(myDGV); to the initialization code.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this without using reflection by accessing the horizontal or vertical scrollbars on your DataGridView control like this. Replace `HScrollBar` with `VScrollBar` to get the vertical scroll bar.

```
public MyFormConstructor()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddScrollListener(MyGrid, MyScrollEventHandler);
}

private void AddScrollListener(DataGridView dgv, ScrollEventHandler scrollEventHandler)
{
   HScrollBar scrollBar = dgv.Controls.OfType<HScrollBar>().First();
   scrollBar.Scroll += scrollEventHandler;
}

private void MyScrollEventHandler(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
   // Handler with e.Type set properly
}
```