# DataGridView Scroll event (and ScrollEventType.EndScroll)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

When handing the `DataGridView.Scroll` event, you can check whether it was the end of the scroll (when dragging the scroll bar with the mouse, this is presumably when the mouse button is released).

The problem is that this never seems to happen. `e.Type` is never `ScrollEventType.EndScroll`

What's wrong with this? How can I do something only when scrolling finishes?

```
    private void dataGridView_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
        {
            // ...      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it seems that this event is just bugged.

You can latch on the the DGV's private scroll bar objects (via reflection) and handle their events, where `ScrollEventType.EndScroll` appears as expected.

See this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472389/how-can-i-receive-the-scroll-box-type-scroll-events-from-a-datagridview/767603#767603) link for how to do it.