# How can you determine when the user scrolls to the bottom of a DataGridView?

Tags: .net, datagridview, scroll, scrollbar, winforms

I am writing a C# Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2008. I have a DataGridView with a lot of data in it. I would like to initially only populate 10,000 rows and add more only when the user scrolls to the bottom. I am handling the DataGridView's Scroll event, but it never seems to raise with the ScrollEventArgs.Type property set to Last, which is the condition I think I need to catch to add more rows. I have read about people having bad experiences with the DataGridView.Scroll event (e.g. [DataGridView Scroll event (and ScrollEventType.EndScroll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785200/datagridview-scroll-event-and-scrolleventtype-endscroll)), but the solution provided ([How can I receive the "scroll box" type scroll events from a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472389/how-can-i-receive-the-scroll-box-type-scroll-events-from-a-datagridview/767603#767603)) only adds the ScrollEventArgs.Type property to come back as EndScroll, not Last like I need. Does anybody know how to get the event to raise properly, or another way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the DataGridView's virtual mode ([Microsoft's virtual mode walkthrough)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx), which is designed for handling very large data sets.  In virtual mode, you can catch the `CellValueNeeded` event.  When the `DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs.RowIndex` is 10,000, you can add more rows to the table.