# datagridview Scroll event not firing when scrolling using keyboard

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to capture the moment when a user ends horizontal scrolling in a datagridview. I need this to reposition buttons in the grid's header.

What I have done so far is adding a scrollListener which I found on this link: [How can I receive the "scroll box" type scroll events from a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472389/how-can-i-receive-the-scroll-box-type-scroll-events-from-a-datagridview/767603#767603)

This works very well, exept that scrolling using the keyboard does not fires the scroll event. When I hoover the mouse in my code over the Scroll event it states "Occurs when the scroll box has been moved by either a mouse or keyboard action". So the event should fire when scrolling with the keyboard, but it does not.

My code is this :

```
    bool addScrollListener(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        // capture horizonal scrolling and redirect to s_Scroll. Purpose is to redraw buttons after scrolling
        bool Result = false;

        Type t = dgv.GetType();
        PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("HorizontalScrollBar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        ScrollBar s = null;

        if (pi != null)
            s = pi.GetValue(dgv, null) as ScrollBar;

        if (s != null)
        {
            s.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(s_Scroll);

            Result = true;
        }

        return Result;
    }

    void s_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        // if grid is done scrolling horizontal, than redraw our buttons
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
        {
            // code works well, but only get here when scrolling with mouse
            PositionButtons();
        }
    }
```

So my problem is that when the user scrolls using the mouse the s_Scroll event is fired, but when scrolling using the keyboard the s_Scroll event is not fired at all.

My question is how do I fix this so the event gets fired in both cases,
and if that is not possible is there another way to capture the end of a horizontal scroll from a datagridview.

Comment: Did you try with the `ValueChanged` event instead of the `Scroll` event ?

Comment: Do you need the requirement that the button positioning only happens when the user is done with scrolling?

Comment: the ValueChanged event sounds good, but how can I use it to find out that the user has stopped scrolling horizontal ? When the user holds down the right-arrow key and lets go after scrolling for example 8 columns, than I want to do my code, not 8 times.

Answer (score 1):

In `DataGridView`, keyboard actions are handled by the `DataGridView` to update the current cell position.

You must use `ScrollBar.ValueChanged` event and compare `ScrollBar.Value` with `ScrollBar.Maximum` to do what you want.

---

You have another solution to do what you want instead of adding an event listener on `ScrollBar.Scroll` : handle the `DataGridView.Scroll` event and verify the datagridview is scrolled down by using `DataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` property and `DataGridView.DisplayedRowCount(true)` method.

That would be simpler and safer.

Comment: the ValueChanged event sounds good, but how can I use it to find out that the user has stopped scrolling horizontal ? When the user holds down the right-arrow key and lets go after scrolling for example 8 columns, than I want to do my code, not 8 times.

Comment: The example you gave using the scroll event and FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex, does this not works for vertical scrolling in stead of horizontal scrolling ? I need it for horizontal scrolling.

Comment: It also works with horizontal scrolling with these methods : `FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex` and `DisplayedColumnCount(true)`.

Comment: For your first comment : `ScrollBar.Value` gives you the scrolling position, so you can run your code depending on the exact position of the scrolling comparing to `Minimum` and `Maximum`.

Comment: Forgive me for being a bit slow today, but how does comparing the Value property to Minumn and Maximum tells me the user has stopped scrolling ? For example the datagrid has 20 columns, the user is on the 2th column and holds down the right-arrow until he is on the 16th column. At this time I need to call my code, so at this time I need to know he stopped scrolling.

Comment: I have the same question for the FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex en DisplayedColumnCount(true) method

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. There is no way to know that. You can stop and restart a timer in the Scroll event, so that your code only runs when the user has stopped scrolling for a while (50 ms for example).

Answer (score 0):

```
private void TransactionsDGV_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.End)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGridViewCell cell = TransactionsDGV.Rows[TransactionsDGV.Rows.Count-2].Cells[0];
        TransactionsDGV.CurrentCell = cell;
        TransactionsDGV.BeginEdit(true);
        TransactionsDGV.EndEdit();
    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Home)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        DataGridViewCell cell = TransactionsDGV.Rows[0].Cells[0];
        TransactionsDGV.CurrentCell = cell;
        TransactionsDGV.BeginEdit(true);
        TransactionsDGV.EndEdit();
    }
}
```